# what is error 9 from tcgetattr, in case of serial communication

Tags: c, linux

I making a c program to read data from a serial device. I am getting 5 values from serial device and I have made a logic through which it is automatically updating values. It runs properly but after sometime it hangs and shows error `error 9 from tcgetattr`.
I have used the code from one of the answers to this question `http://tinyurl.com/keuxkgz`
Error is in the function `void set_blocking (int fd, int should_block)` and `int set_interface_attribs (int fd, int speed, int parity)` . I am not able to remove it. Please help. Thanks.!

Comment: There's a bug in your code somewhere - we can't see your code, so it's hard to tell where it is. But my bet is you have a buffer overflow somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not going to look at external sources. However, `errno == 9 == EBADF` in Linux. It means your file descriptor (`fd`) is incorrect.

Instead of printing just `errno`, I recommend you use something like

```
if (...) {
    const int errnum = errno;
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: tcsetattr() failed: %s (%d)\n", devicepath, strerror(errnum), errnum);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

where `devicepath` is the variable containing the path to the serial device you're using. (You need to `#include <string.h>` for `strerror()`, `#include <errno.h>` for `errno`, and `#include <stdlib.h>` for `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE`.)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me due to permission denial to open the serial port.

After I executed the program with superuser privileges, "sudo" the error disappeared.